# How to get the actual latest event on back pressure in Rxjava2? Flowable.onBackpressureLatest() not worked as expected

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, backpressure

When a producer produces event faster than a customer consumes.

I thought using [Flowable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html) with [onBackpressureLatest()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#onBackpressureLatest--), I can get the latest event emitted.

But it turns out there's a default buffer of size 128. What I got was the dated event buffered previously.

So how can I get the actual latest event?

Here's the sample code:

```
Flowable.interval(40, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnNext{
                println("doOnNext $it")
            }
            .onBackpressureLatest()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .subscribe {
                println("subscribe $it")
                Thread.sleep(100)
            }
```

What I expected:

```
doOnNext    0
    subscribe   0
doOnNext    1
doOnNext    2
    subscribe   2
doOnNext    3
doOnNext    4
doOnNext    5
    subscribe   5
doOnNext    6
doOnNext    7
    subscribe   7
doOnNext    8
doOnNext    9
doOnNext    10
    subscribe   10
...
```

What I got:

```
doOnNext    0
    subscribe   0
doOnNext    1
doOnNext    2
    subscribe   1
doOnNext    3
doOnNext    4
doOnNext    5
    subscribe   2
doOnNext    6
doOnNext    7
    subscribe   3
doOnNext    8
doOnNext    9
doOnNext    10
    subscribe   4
...
doOnNext    325
    subscribe   127
doOnNext    326
doOnNext    327
doOnNext    328
    subscribe   246
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem actually lies in `observeOn`, which requests up to 128 items by default and passes this request up to `backpressureLatest`, which as a consequence does not behave as you're expecting.

You can use [`.observeOn(Scheduler,boolean,int)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-int-) to specify the buffer size which should fix the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Please also note that, even with the smallest value of 1 for `observeOn()`, there is still a buffer of size 1 for `onBackpressureLatest()`. Since `observeOn()` has to move data across a thread boundary, you will have one emission being processed while one is in the pipeline, so to speak.